# Can I apply the same styling to two elements together in jQuery by grouping them like in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, readability

This is simply for keeping code neater. In CSS I can group elements like this:

```
.element1,
.element2,
.element3,
.element4,
.element5,
.element6 {
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

is there anything similar in jQuery or would I have to set each separately.

```
$('.element1').css('font-weight', 'bold');
$('.element2').css('font-weight', 'bold');
$('.element3').css('font-weight', 'bold');
etc
```

I suppose I imagine something like

```
$('.element1', '.element2', etc).css('font-weight', 'bold);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even more simple, you can use precisely the same selector in jQuery as you could in CSS:

```
$('.element1, .element2').css('font-weight', 'bold);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes, you can do that. But group your selectors using CSS syntax.

```
$('.element1, .element2, .element3').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.element1, .element2, etc').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

[JQuery multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

```
Except you want it like this: $('.element1,.element2').css('font-weight', 'bold);
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Example:

```
$("div,span,p.myClass").css("border","3px solid red");
```